# replacing many files in a directory with newly created files using python3

Tags: python

I've used the Python 3 code below to change files with names like:

CT-8873-0002
CT-8873-0003
...

to names like

CT-008-0002.dcm
CT-008-0003.dcm
...

But I need to change the names to the new names in the actual directory. Can't seem to do this. Tried many things.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import os
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\franc\\Desktop\\CT-INSPIRIUM-8873')   
    import glob 
    for fileName1 in glob.glob('CT-*'):
            fileName1 = fileName1.split('-')
            fileName1[1] = '008'
            fileName1 = '-'.join(fileName1)
            fileName2 = fileName1
     print(fileName2)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching on stackoverflow? Because there is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-multiple-files-in-a-directory-in-python#2759130

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748228/rename-multiple-files-in-python)

Comment: The files are initially listed in Windows 10 without .dcm and listed vertically

Answer (score 0):

Your code just creates a new string `fileName2` and print it out, it doesn't change your existing files names.

One solution is wrap `mv` command by python:

```
import os
os.system('mv original_filename new_filename')
```

In your case:

```
 for fileName1 in glob.glob('CT-*'):
     fileName1 = fileName1.split('-')
     fileName1[1] = '008'
     fileName1 = '-'.join(fileName1)
     fileName2 = fileName1

     // add below
     os.system('mv {old_name} {new_name}'.format(old_name=fileName1, new_name=fileName2))
```

Make sure test your code before execute it on your real data file

Comment: Since OP is using python3 why not going directly for [`os.renames`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=os%20remove#os.renames) ?

Comment: @davinellulinvega can't agree more!  your solution is much clean and short!

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on @haifzhan answer, if you are already using python3, you have in fact many methods available for file or directory renaming hidden within the `os` module. Depending on your exact problem, you can either use `os.renames`, `os.rename` or `os.replace`. Per the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=os%20remove#os.replace), `os.replace` is better cross-platform-wise. Which means that your code could simply be:

```
import os

for fileName1 in glob.glob('CT-*'):
     fileName2 = fileName1.split('-')
     fileName2[1] = '008'
     fileName2 = '-'.join(fileName2)
     # Does the renaming
     os.replace(fileName1, fileName2)
```

Comment: Well glad it helped without too much hassle for you. Have a nice time programming in python.