# Rename multiple images randomly from a list of keywords using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to rename multiple images using `os.rename()` in Python from a
list `keyword_name` randomly so I break it into these steps:

1. `def keyword()`

   - keyword_name a list that holds keyword
   - loop through list
   - assign a variable that holds the index(list[])

```
import os
keyword_name = "key.jpg","alph.jpg","hold.jpg","name.jpg","kid.jpg",
"young","zolo","lima0","sofia","temra","tooad","aeder","ed","de","cf","fc"
def keyword():
    index = 0
    while index < len(keyword_name):
        keyword = keyword_name[index]
        print(keyword)
        index += 1
```

2. def `rename_name()`

   - returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.
   - returns current working directory of a process.

```
def renam_name():
        file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Desktop\cLine\file")
        saved_path =os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(r"C:\Desktop\cLine\file")
    for f in file_list:
        #spilt text to file_name,img_type
        file_name, img_type = os.path.splitext(f)
        #convert the tuple to a list
        keyword = list(file_name)
        #join the list 
        name = "".join(keyword)
        print(name)
        os.rename(name, keyword_name)
```

I am new to programming. I did some research, but I only found how to remove integers or a string from `file_name`. I'll be so thankful if somebody can help me.

The sources I've been looking at:

[Rename multiple files in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-multiple-files-in-a-directory-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Rename multiple files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748228/rename-multiple-files-in-python)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `keyword` method()? Because it just prints each item from the `keyword_name` and increments an unused `index`. Did you intend to get a random name from `keyword` and use it for `os.rename`?

Comment: yes that exactly what i am trying to do os.rename(name, keyword_name)
but i got stuck how to bring keyword[index] +1 and store it to a variable and change to  str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many parts of your code that aren't needed.

The `keyword` method should randomly select a keyword from `keyword_name`.
Then, call it to provide the 2nd argument to `os.rename`.

Try this (I placed comments inline):

```
import os
import random


# Use a list instead of a tuple so that we can modify
keyword_name = ["key","alph","hold","name","kid", "young","zolo","lima0","sofia","temra","tooad","aeder","ed","de","cf","fc"]


def keyword():
    # Generate a random index
    rand_index = random.randint(0, len(keyword_name)-1)

    # Get the keyword 
    rand_keyword = keyword_name[rand_index]

    # Remove the used-up keyword from the list to
    # prevent randomly selecting it again when renaming
    keyword_name.remove(rand_keyword)

    return rand_keyword


def renam_name():
    os.chdir(r"<path-to-image-folder>")
    file_list = os.listdir(r"<path-to-image-folder>")
    for f in file_list:
        # get the file extension
        file_name, img_type = os.path.splitext(f)   

        # Call the random keyword generator then use the return
        # value as the new file name. 
        os.rename(f, keyword() + img_type)


renam_name()
```

In addition, since keywords are chosen at random, you'll have to prevent selecting the *same* keyword, so that the code will not rename the file to a previously renamed file. To do this, I remove the already-chosen keyword from `keyword_name` (I needed to change `keyword_name` to a `list` because `tuple`s are immutable).

It might be also better to remove the ".jpg" extensions from the `keyword_name` list, as those will produce new filenames like "name.jpg.png".