# how to rename multiple files at once using python

Tags: python

I have multiple files in a directory :

```
00- filename1
01- filename2
02- filename3
03- filename4
```

etc.
I am trying to replace 00 in the file name with 01, and 01 ==> 02 Using Python.
which would result in the following:

```
01- filename1
02- filename2
03- filename3
04- filename4
```

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. Go ahead and try it out. Let us know if you have a specific answerable question, and we'll help you out then :-)

Comment: i have all file names in one list .
now how can i use os.rename function for each filename

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748228/rename-multiple-files-in-python)

Comment: why python? wouldn't `mv` + `sed` do the same?

Comment: Did the below solution help? If so, feel free to accept, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Start by considering how you'd approach this with a `list`. Note f-strings, or formatted string literals, are available in Python 3.6+.

```
A = ['00- filename1', '01- filename2', '02- filename3', '03- filename4']

def renamer(x):
    num, name = x.split('-')
    newnum = str(int(num)+1).zfill(2)
    return f'{newnum}-{name}'

res = [renamer(i) for i in A]

print(res)

['01- filename1', '02- filename2', '03- filename3', '04- filename4']
```

Then incorporate this into file cycling logic. For example:

```
import os

for fn in os.listdir('.'):
    os.rename(fn, renamer(fn))
```