# Python - Renaming file

Tags: python, rename, xls

I am trying to rename a set of files in a folder from .Xlsx to .xls. This is what I have done thus far:

```
allFiles = glob.glob("/*.Xlsx") # Folder that has all the files
renamed = []
for filename in allFiles:
    if filename.endswith(".Xlsx"):
        os.rename(filename, filename[:-5])
        renamed.append(filename[:-5]) # removed the .Xlsx extension
        os.path.join(renamed, '.xls') # this fails
```

I am trying to see how can I have .xls added to the above list `renamed`

Comment: Besides the renaming: you are aware that making these renames won't change the unferlying file types or structure, right? I.e. old ms. excel versions will still be unable to open then - it is not just a name change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Comment: folks, while you are at it, one might try posting an answer using pathlib and its methods, instead of "glob", "os.path.join" and filename[:-5] to strip the suffix.

Comment: For multile files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748228/rename-multiple-files-in-python

Answer (score 4):

If I read that line by line, I think

This is removing all the .xlsx extensions of the file on disk

```
os.rename(filename, filename[:-5])         # Problem 1
```

Then adds the name without extension to the list

```
renamed.append(filename[:-5])
```

and then tries to join something a) on the whole array and b) on a file and its extension rather than two paths

```
os.path.join(renamed, '.xls')             # Problem 2 and 3
```

You'd rather

```
newname = filename[:-5]                  # remove extension
newname = newname + ".xls"               # add new extension
os.rename(filename, newname)             # rename correctly
renamed.append( ... )                    # Whatever name you want in the list
```

Also note that `if filename.endswith(".Xlsx"):` might be `False` for all files that end in lower case `.xlsx`.

Instead of `[:-5]`, you could use the help of the operating system as well:

```
import glob
import os

allFiles = glob.glob("c:/test/*.xlsx")
renamed = []
for filename in allFiles:
    path, filename = os.path.split(filename)
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if extension == ".xlsx":
        destination = os.path.join(path, basename+".xls")
        os.rename(filename, destination)
```

And just FYI: if renaming is the sole purpose of the program, try `ren *.xlsx *.xls` at the Windows command prompt.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried to do the above but I get an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file1.Xlsx -> file1/.xls`. But I can see the `File1.Xlsx` in the folder despite executing the rename method above

Comment: yes I am aware that this will only work if the file extension is '.Xlsx'

Comment: @scottmartin: good catch. `os.path.join` will work for paths only and add slashes (backslashes) as needed. It's not useful for concatenating strings

Answer (score 1):

1. With your glob call, `if filename.endswith(".Xlsx"):` should always be true.
2. You mix up your order:

   ```
   os.rename(filename, filename[:-5])  # this renames foo.Xlsx to foo, everything after it is too late.
   renamed.append(filename[:-5]) # This adds the file w/o the extension, but also w/o the new extension.
   os.path.join(renamed, '.xls') # This is a statement which would produce a result if called correctly (i. e. with a string instead of a list), but the result is discarded.
   ```

   Instead, do

   ```
   basename = filename[:-5]
   newname = os.path.join(basename, '.xls')
   os.rename(filename, newname)
   renamed.append(basename) # or newname? Choose what you need.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're currently dividing the process in the following steps:

- Remove the xlsx extension
- Add the file to a list (without extension)
- Add the new extension to the file (this fails because `os.path.join` won't take a list as input)

To keep it simpler, I would only rename to the new extension, and if you need the `renamed` list, populate it. Like so:

```
allFiles = glob.glob("/*.Xlsx") <- Folder that has all the files
renamed = []
for filename in allFiles:
    if filename.endswith(".Xlsx"):
        new_name = filename[:-5]+'.xls'
        os.rename(filename, new_name)
        renamed.append(new_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

`os.path.join` does not rename the file. You should directly rename it with the `os.rename` method by doing:

```
os.rename(filename, filename[:-5]+'.xls')
```