# How to rename image name in a folder using python?

Tags: python

I have over 2000 images in a folder that needs to be renamed. Currently, it's a default name as `w=0&h=-_BACl339n_c4PTZDlVgaHWg9s1k_Vyz8PbhNhhXkQk=0` and I need it to name it as `fear_1` and all the other images in this format. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried searching for similar posts? [Rename multiple files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748228/rename-multiple-files-in-python), [Renaming multiple files in a directory using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37467561/2745495), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.listdir` to get all the filenames and `os.rename` to rename them

```
import os
path = '//path//to//folder'
files = os.listdir(path)


for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join(['fear_',str(index+1), '.jpg'])))
```